# partial fractions decomposition issue

Tags: partial-fractions

How do you decompose the following fraction?

$$\frac{2}{2x^2 (x+1)} = \frac{a}{2x^2} + \frac{b}{x+1}$$

i just want to know if I am on the right track or I am missing something(based on the above beginning).

Comment: Not quite, choose $$\frac{Ax+B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x}+\frac{D}{x+1}$$ First of all, cancel out the $2$ on the left side

Comment: @Peter A constant numerator is sufficient, i.e. you don't need $Ax+B$ but simply $A$ will do. Your suggestion will work too of course, but you don't need the extra coefficient.

Comment: @StackTD You are right, we have $\frac{A}{x}$ and $\frac{C}{x}$, which we can sum up to $\frac{A'}{x}$

Comment: @Peter Indeed. You only need a linear numerator for (natural powers of) irreducible quadratic factors in the denominator (i.e. with no real roots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you can cancel the common factor $2$ first.

Since $x=0$ is a double root, you need to take:
$$\frac{1}{x^2 (x+1)} = \frac{a}{x^2} + \frac{b}{x} + \frac{c}{x+1}$$
Can you take it from there?

---

Sometimes, you can avoid having to solve a system (in your case of three linear equations in three unknowns) to find the coefficients/numerators with a few handy manipulations.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2 (x+1)} 
& = \frac{1\color{blue}{+x-x}}{x^2 (x+1)} \\[5pt]
&  = \frac{1+x}{x^2 (x+1)} - \frac{x}{x^2 (x+1)} \\[5pt]
&  = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x (x+1)}\\[5pt]
&  = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1\color{blue}{+x-x}}{x (x+1)}\\[5pt]
&  = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1+x}{x (x+1)}+\frac{x}{x (x+1)}\\[5pt]
&  = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+1}
\end{align}$$